# using nsautolayout make a group of uiview in the center of their superview

Tags: autolayout

I would like to make numbers of uiview in the center of the red area.
How could I do that with NSAutolayout ? Even when users rotate?

landscape mode

top

....................................

```
       - view -              ... 200px margin from right
           | gap
       - view -
           | gap
       - view -
           | gap
       - view -
```

....................................

bottom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question isn't really clear.

You can create constraints to center a view with respect to another view in a given orientation. For example, you can set one view's "centerX" attribute to equal some other view's centerX. (You could also make it equal that other view's leading, trailing, left, or right edge. Or even other attributes that don't make much intuitive sense, like width, top, etc., if that's what you want.)

If you're trying to vertically center a group like the stack of views in your diagram, there are a couple of approaches. First, you can embed the group into another view that closely encloses it. Its top would equal the top of the first view in the stack and its bottom would equal the bottom of the last view in the stack. Then you could set up a constraint to keep that container view centered within its superview.

The other approach is to create hidden spacer views. Put one view, the top spacer, above the first view in your stack. Make its top equal the top of the superview. Make its bottom equal the top of the first view in your stack. Similarly, set up a spacer at the bottom. Its top would equal the bottom of the last view in your stack. Its bottom would equal the bottom of the superview. Then, set a constraint between the top spacer and the bottom spacer to make their heights equal. That ensures that the space between the stack and the superview is the same on the top and the bottom.

The same techniques work for the horizontal direction, too, if necessary.

---

Update:

Here's some code which I haven't tested at all:

```
UIView* redArea = /* ... */;
NSArray* stackViews = /* ... */;

UIView* container = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:NSZeroRect];

[redArea addSubview:container];

UIView* previousView = nil;
for (UIView* view in stackViews)
{
    [container addSubview:view];
    if (previousView)
    {
        // Make a gap between the stacked views
        NSDictionary* views = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(view, previousView);
        NSArray* constraints = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:[previousView]-[view]" options:0 metrics:nil views:views];
        [container addConstaints:constraints];
    }
    else
    {
        // Make the top of the container the same as the top of the first stacked view
        NSDictionary* views = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(view);
        NSArray* constraints = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[view]" options:0 metrics:nil views:views];
        [container addConstaints:constraints];
    }

    // Make sure the container is at least as wide as each stacked view
    NSDictionary* views = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(view);
    NSArray* constraints = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-(>=0)-[view]-(>=0)-|" options:0 metrics:nil views:views];
    [container addConstaints:constraints];

    previousView = view;
}

if (previousView)
{
    // Make the bottom of the container the same as the bottom of the last stacked view
    NSDictionary* views = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(previousView);
    NSArray* constraints = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:[previousView]|" options:0 metrics:nil views:views];
    [container addConstaints:constraints];
}

// Make the container as narrow as possible after satisfying other constraints
NSLayoutConstraint* minimalWidth = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:container attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:nil attribute:NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute multiplier:1 constant:0];
minimalWidth.priority = UILayoutPriorityFittingSizeLevel - 1;
[container addConstraint:minimalWidth];

// Center the container within the red area
NSLayoutConstraint* centerVertically = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:container attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:redArea attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY multiplier:1 constant:0];
NSLayoutConstraint* centerHorizontally = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:container attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:redArea attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX multiplier:1 constant:0];
[redArea addConstraints:@[centerVertically, centerHorizontally]];
```

This would all be easier to set up in IB.

Comment: Thanks, your first approach is what I want to. Is it possible to give some hints about how to code that with constraints. When I put all the sub views into one view to be their container.

Comment: seems I can't put the last three sentence into the viewdidload to init these constraints. Because at that time the redArea hasn't put onto the screen yet.

Comment: I did get an error about the constraints. After I put above codes into the viewdidappear to layout the redArea's subviews, everything is going fine. I think I have to make the redArea be on the screen before using constraint to layout its subview. In the other word, I can't using these code in initwithframe or init methods.